# How to properly use GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer() on android with VBOs?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I am trying to get a simple 2D square to appear on the screen, but I am running into a problem with the last argument in the method GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer().

Here's my code(the draw() method):

```
public void draw(float[] matrix){
        int shaderHandle = shader.getShaderHandle();
        int mMVPMatrixHandle;

        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderHandle);
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderHandle, "vPosition");

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderHandle, "uMVPMatrix");
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, matrix, 0);
        MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle,COORDS_PER_VERTEX,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,ibo);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,DRAW_ORDER.length,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,null);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    }
```

The problem is in this line:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle,COORDS_PER_VERTEX,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);
```

I'm using Android Studio, and it is telling me that I can't pass `0` as the last argument in this method, it requires a Buffer object.

In order to use my VBO, I'm told I must have a zero as the last argument. How do I do this?

The logcat entry I receive is as follows:

```
06-23 22:27:23.098 2709-2709/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-23 22:27:23.222 2709-2709/com.example.android.opengl W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.opengl-2/lib/x86
06-23 22:27:23.362 2709-2709/com.example.android.opengl W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.opengl-2/lib/x86
06-23 22:27:23.432 2709-2730/com.example.android.opengl D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                          [ 06-23 22:27:23.439  2709: 2709 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab9e4670, tid 2709


                                                                          [ 06-23 22:27:23.472  2709: 2730 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf4471b0, tid 2730
06-23 22:27:23.474 2709-2730/com.example.android.opengl I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                          [ 06-23 22:27:23.506  2709: 2729 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab9e4ac0, tid 2729
06-23 22:27:23.557 2709-2729/com.example.android.opengl I/System.out: DEBUG
06-23 22:27:23.562 2709-2729/com.example.android.opengl E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4093c00
06-23 22:27:23.565 2709-2729/com.example.android.opengl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 129
                                                                          Process: com.example.android.opengl, PID: 2709
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.nio.Buffer.remaining()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.opengl.GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.java:1913)
                                                                              at com.example.android.opengl.Sprite.draw(Sprite.java:105)
                                                                              at com.example.android.opengl.MyGLRenderer.onDrawFrame(MyGLRenderer.java:76)
                                                                              at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
                                                                              at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
06-23 22:27:23.607 2709-2730/com.example.android.opengl E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa3b11230
```

Comment: Can you give us the logcat error statement that you are getting?

Comment: I have added the logcat above

Comment: I still stand by my answer below, have you tried it?

Comment: Actually, I just figured out my problem. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

The problem was not with my code at all, it was with the version of the Android SDK I was using. There is a very simple fix to this.

You simply have to change the project's SDK settings (compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion) to an appropriate version. I changed the version to 14 for minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion, because this version contains the full(enough) support of OpenGL ES 2.0 to do what I want it to, and almost no one uses devices with a lower SDK version than 14 anymore.

Comment: Yes, this entry point was missing in the original ES20 bindings introduced in API level 8, and added in API level 9. You can see this in the API documentation, where the API level for each entry point is listed. At least they fixed it within one version. It took them 6 versions to fix some missing entries in the ES30 bindings, and others still appear to be missing in version 24.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your logcat output, so I do not know exactly what the error is. However, I have a guess; get rid of the last two glBindBuffer lines.

```
public void draw(float[] matrix){
    int shaderHandle = shader.getShaderHandle();
    int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderHandle);
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderHandle, "vPosition");

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderHandle, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, matrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle,COORDS_PER_VERTEX,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,ibo);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,DRAW_ORDER.length,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,null);

}
```